# Captcha not working in Forgot password Frontend in magento2.1.x

Tags: magento2, captcha

Magento2.1 version in forgot password page captcha not working while I am entering the true captcha.[image]

**Finally i found it magento core issue. Does anyone face this issue? any idea how to solve it?**

Comment: Any solutions about that?